# javascript pass obj to string replace

Tags: javascript, regex

i have object with keys and values , i want to pass this object to replace function and replace key with value

```js
function highlight(){
  var mapObj = {} //this is the obj to pass to replace

  //get the input value
  var whatInTextInput = document.querySelector(".toGetText").value;

  //trim and split the string into array of words
  var whatInTextInput_words_array = whatInTextInput.trim().split(' ');
  
  //build the object with keys and value
  for(let item in whatInTextInput_words_array){
    mapObj[whatInTextInput_words_array[item]] = "<mark class='highlight'>"+[whatInTextInput_words_array[item]]+"</mark>"
  }
    
  // this is just the test string
  var str = "I have a cat, a dog, and a goat.";
  
  //here how to pass mapObj instead of /cat|dog|goat/gi ???
  str = str.replace(/cat|dog|goat/gi, function(key) {
    return mapObj[key];
  });
   
  //show the final result
  document.querySelector(".inputText").innerHTML = str;
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="highlight()">Highlight</button>
<input type="text" class="toGetText"/>
<div class="inputText">I have a cat, a dog, and a goat.</div>
```

And if i didn't type the other words i got undefined as a result.

How to pass `mapObj` obj which has keys and value to replace function, instead of const value `/cat|dog|goat/`?

Comment: please how i can clarify the question ??? i want to pass object to the replace function instead of cont value cat|dog|goat

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: i am trying to understand how replace is working and how to pass obj as value

Comment: Your regex `cat|dog|goat` matches all 3 words: cat, dog and goat. Please elaborate on each stage of your algorithm and its purpose

Comment: This code will highlight cat, dog and goat when user enters cat dog goat in the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to get the words from your user input and build a regex from them. `.replace` simply takes a regex; it does not deal with objects directly.

There are some subtle points here: You'll need to escape any regex meta-characters, and you need to make sure any keys that are prefixes of other keys are listed later (e.g. if you have both `cat` and `caterpillar`, the regex needs to be `caterpillar|cat`, not `cat|caterpillar`, or else `caterpillar` will never match).

It's not a good idea to have a mapping object in this case, either: You want to do case insensitive matching, so you can't just pre-compute a replacement string: If you don't normalize your matched strings, you'll just get `undefined` (because e.g. `CaT` isn't among the keys), and if you do, you'll destroy the original case of the text (e.g. `CaT` would turn into `<mark class="highlight">cat</mark>` (all lowercase)).

The easiest solution is to take all words from the input string, sort them by descending length (to ensure any prefix strings are listed later), escape all regex metacharacters, and join them with `|`. However, if the input list is empty, that would result in `''` (a string that matches everywhere), and we want it to match nowhere, so just use `/^(?!)/` in that case (a regex that never matches).

Then get the `.textContent` of the target element, do the replacement (computing the replacement HTML dynamically to preserve the original case, and making sure to escape all HTML metacharacters properly), and put it back into `.innerHTML`.

Somewhat like this:

```js
function highlight() {
  const mapObj = {};
  const whatInTextInput = document.querySelector(".toGetText").value;
  const whatInTextInput_words_array = whatInTextInput.match(/\S+/g) || [];
  
  const regex_str = whatInTextInput_words_array.sort(function (a, b) {
    const na = a.length, nb = b.length;
    return (
      na > nb ? -1 :
      na < nb ? 1 :
      a < b ? -1 :
      b < a ? 1 :
      0
    );
  })
  .map(s => s.replace(/\W/g, "\\$&"))
  .join('|');
  const regex = whatInTextInput_words_array.length ? new RegExp(regex_str, 'gi') : /^(?!)/;

  const inputText = document.querySelector('.inputText');
  const str = inputText.textContent;
  
  inputText.innerHTML = str.replace(regex, function (word) {
    return (
      '<mark class="highlight">' +
      word.replace(/[<>&]/g, c => '&#' + c.charCodeAt(0) + ';') +  // hacky HTML escape
      '</mark>'
    );
  });
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="highlight()">Highlight</button>

<input type="text" class="toGetText"/>

<div class="inputText">
I have a cat, a dog, and a goat.
</div>
```

Comment: thank you a lot , this is what i was searching for have a nice day